# Priority of logarithm

Tags: definition

In an expression like the following one, which one of log or multiply does have priority? In other words, does it equal $\log(V\times V)$ or does it equal $\log(V)\times V$?

$\log V \times V$

Comment: That sort of expression is best avoided! Mathematicians rarely write multiplication by $\times$ anyway.

Comment: I would assume that means $\log(V) \times V$. Usually when you have a "named function" like $\sin$, $\log$, etc, if there aren't parentheses if usually just applies to whatever comes first. This is just a general observation though, and expressions like that should be avoided for sake of clarity.

Comment: I'd go with the latter but I had to think about it. I mean otherwise why wouldn't he have written $\log V^2$? Whether or not the rules of notation made his expression unambiguous or not, everyone, in my opinion, should just remove all doubt and write $V\log V$ (or even better $V\log(V)$, or log(V^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression in parenthesis always takes priority before multiplication, no matter the function you are working with.

Comment: The expression doesn't have any parantheses.

Comment: In that case, the log would be computed first.